# Не переведены некоторые надписи в комментариях

Tags: дефект, локализация, комментарии

> [image]

---

> [image]

---

> [image]

---

Насколько я понимаю, это эти строки:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15927
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15928
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15929
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15930
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15944
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15945
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15946
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15951
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15952
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15953
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15955

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Утвердил предложенные переводы и добавил несколько новых.

Будет в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.12.10.40969

Не забывайте, что вы можете сами предлагать переводы прямо в [traducir](https://ru.traducir.win/), их останется только утвердить, если всё нормально. В данном случае они достаточно простые.